# NGINX url rewrite to rest endpoints on a different port

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I want to do a url rewrite to redirect all request with /api to a different port.
I want to redirect all /api request to this http://localhost:8081/api
I tried to create a rewrite rule like this but it returns a 404:

```
location /api {
    rewrite           ^/api/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass        http://localhost:8081/api;
}
```

Edit: It tried to update using the suggestion from the comment using this curl

```
curl -i GET "http://localhost/api/healthcheck/check" -H "accept: */*"
```

With the following response:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: GET
HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway
Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Mon, 10 Aug 2020 23:56:17 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 182
Connection: keep-alive
```

Heres my whole comfig

```
server {
access_log /var/log/nginx/access_log.log;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error_log.log;
listen        80;
server_name   ui.buildanalyzer.io;
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
  location /api {
       proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/api;       
  }
    
}
```

Comment: Your code removes the `/api` from the original request, so a request to `http://example.com/api` is sent to `http://localhost:8081/`. If you need to keep the `/api` part, remove the `rewrite...break` statement.

Comment: its returning 404. unable to resolve GET when trying to do a curl request. port 80 is serving a vue application and the redirect should serve json

Comment: got an error method not allowed

Comment: Please add output of `nginx -T` in your question. Please also add exact commands and output of the commands what you are using to test.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: You should remove the stray `GET` from the `curl` command. It does nothing here except throw an error, since there is no such host.

Comment: Im getting a bad getway

Answer (score 0):

Finally make it work! Here is my configuration

```
location /api {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5021;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

I can call all GET endpoints but the problem is i cannot make all POST work. I also achieved to display the endpoint documentation using almost identical configuration.